# Grammar of regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex

I am new regular expression. Suppose I want to get the regular expression for a string "1994-02-14 00:00:00, 12345", now I have a expression:

```
.*\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}[\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}]?\,\\d{5}.
```

But when I use

```
grepl(pattern = "^.*\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}[\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}]?\,\\d{5}", x= x )
```

It gives the following error:'\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}]?\,"
How should I solve this error? In other words, what is the correct regular expression for the above string?

Thank you!!

Comment: Your pattern appears to have several problems, but the error you're asking about specifically seems to be due to the single backslash in front of the comma, near the end of the pattern.

Comment: As the message says,  You have `\,`   You probably want `\\,`

Comment: Remove the backslash before comma (comma is not a special character and does not need to be escaped) and use parentheses, not square brackets, around the optional part.  Also you have minus signs in some places where colons should be.

Comment: Can I suggest you use the `rebus` package?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
grepl(pattern = "^.*\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})?, \\d{5}", x= x )
```